# Highchart with background should be Dots instead of Grid

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to set the background of highchart as Dotted line instead of default Grid .Please help me to set the options to set Dot .

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Post your code please....

Comment: If you are trying then you should have code.

Comment: So you have dotted series and you need to set backgorund for chart or something different ?

Answer (score 3):

The option you need is probably:

```
yAxis: {
        gridLineDashStyle: 'longdash',
```

You can use the same option in the xAxis block to format the vertical lines. You can also specify different dash styles. The documentation is here:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.gridLineDashStyle

The dash style options are demonstrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-dashstyle-all/

Comment: Thanks steveP its working ...... yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            tickInterval: 0.5,
            minorTickInterval: 'auto',
            minorGridLineDashStyle: 'Dot',
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: '#00F',
            tickColor: '#000',

Comment: Hi , i have another issue after i change the background as dotted line , the number of dots for minorGridLineDashStyle is not showing correct after i zoom the page to view the dots , but for the grid it shows correct no of lines like 5X5 but the dots are showing more .....do i need to calculate to set the minorTickInterval .pls see the code below    xAxis: {tickInterval: 50,minorTickInterval:'auto',
          minorGridLineDashStyle: 'Dot', gridLineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: '#000',
            tickColor: '#000',
            },

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand what your asking here. Can you create a jsfiddle to show the problem. Also, if my previous answer helped, please accept and/or upvote it to indicate it was correct.

Comment: Hi Steve, yes your previous answer helped me to set the dotted line. thanks but my second question was after i changed to set the dotted line (minorGridLineDashStyle)the number of dots inside the minor grid is not uniform ? .Please see the link  http://jsfiddle.net/LWxhT/

Comment: I don't see any other way to get what you want apart from specifically setting the minorTickInterval to a calculated value.